# Error: No plugins found in repository: grailsCentral

Tags: grails, grails-2.0

I am getting the next error when i run `grails list-plugin` with grails 2.0.1.

**I am not behind a proxy.**

```
| Environment set to development.....
ApacheURLLister found URL=[http://plugins.grails.org/Community].
ApacheURLLister found URL=[http://plugins.grails.org/plugins].
ApacheURLLister found URL=[http://plugins.grails.org/Documentation].
ApacheURLLister found URL=[http://plugins.grails.org/all].
ApacheURLLister found URL=[http://plugins.grails.org/featured].
ApacheURLLister found URL=[http://plugins.grails.org/newest].
ApacheURLLister found URL=[http://plugins.grails.org/supported].
ApacheURLLister found URL=[http://plugins.grails.org/forum].
| Error No plugins found in repository: grailsCentral. This may be because the repository is behind an HTTP proxy.
```

I have recently updated gem to version 1.8.17 while i was trying to install cloud-foundry plugin

### Debugging steps

I have tried the following without success.

- Deleted my $HOME/.grails folder
- Deleting my GRAILS_HOME folder and downloading grails 2.0.1 and installing it again.
- I have tried to create an app from were. Same error:

  $ grails create-app dummyapp

  | Created Grails Application at /Users/sdelamo/Developer/grails/dummyapp

  $ cd dummyapp/

  $ grails list-plugin

  | Environment set to development.....

  | Error No plugins found in repository: grailsCentral. This may be because the repository 
  is behind an HTTP proxy.

I have used grails 2.0.1 in the same machine before without no problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a temporary misconfiguration that happened when we switched the grails.org site to new servers. It's fixed now though.

Answer (score 2):

As of May 22 the repo move started in March seems to be biting if you're not aware. See [Graeme Rocher's post](http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Plugin-publication-migration-HOWTO-td4474812.html)

Specifically, this worked for me:

```
repositories { 
...
// grailsPlugins()
grailsRepo "http://grails.org/plugins" 
...
}
```

Comment: Should have noted that's with an existing 2.0.1 project.